# Can I manipulate a column whilst subsetting in R?

Tags: r, subset, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe of logistic regression summary statistics with column names

`"CHR"   "SNP"   "BP"    "A1"    "TEST"  "NMISS" "OR"    "STAT"  "P"`

I want to make a new dataframe which has three columns:

`"SNP" "A1"` and `"logOR"`

The obvious way to do this would be to make a new column, logOR, then simply subset on those 3 columns.

However, I was wondering if it was possible to perform log(OR) within the subsetting process?

I have tried:

```
raw<-c("SNP","A1","log(OR)")

data.raw<-data[,raw]
```

And R was not too impressed with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may need `grep` if you don't have `logOR` in the column i.e. `data[, grep('SNP|A1|OR", names(data))]`

Comment: if I understood correctly, `dplyr` might be interesting for you: `sel <- data %>%  select(SNP,A1) %>% mutate(logOR = log(OR))`

Comment: The dplyr option worked so long as I specified where OR was coming from: 

sel <- data %>% select(SNP,A1) %>% mutate(logOR = log(data$OR))

Thanks so much!!

Comment: You need to specify `data$OR` because you didn't include OR in your `select` statement. You could flip the functions around like so to avoid that: `sel <- data %>% mutate(logOR = log(OR)) %>% select(SNP, A1, logOR)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `with` is a good and simple way to do this:

```
dat.raw <- with(data, data.frame(SNP,A1,log(OR)))
```

Comment: This also does the business and is definitely easier syntax to remember, although I also like the dplyr answer as I had not previously used dplyr. Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Fastest and cleanest way (imo) is to use base function `transform`

```
transform(data,logOR =  log(OR))[c("SNP","A1","logOR")]
```

---

**Bonus**

There are other ways to do it, I've benchmarked some against each other and give the result for a small and bigger dataset (1000 lines or 100000).

`transform` is the fastest in any case. It's a base function that behaves exactly like mutate in this case.

`with` makes less sense to me "philosophically" here, but it's the shortest line after `data.table` and perform almost on par with `transform` when size goes up.

**small data.frames**

```
library(microbenchmark)    
n <- 1000
data <- data.frame("CHR"=sample(1:n),"SNP"=sample(1:n),"BP"=sample(1:n),"A1"=sample(1:n),"TEST"=sample(1:n),
                   "NMISS"=sample(1:n),"OR"=sample(1:n),"STAT"=sample(1:n),"P"=sample(1:n))
data2 <- as.data.table(data)

microbenchmark(
  transform   = transform(data,logOR =  log(OR))[c("SNP","A1","logOR")],
  within      = within   (data,logOR <- log(OR))[c("SNP","A1","logOR")],
  with        = with     (data, data.frame(SNP,A1,logOR=log(OR))),               # jkt's solution
  mutate      = mutate(data,logOR = log(OR))[c("SNP","A1","logOR")],             # mutate will behave exactly the same as transform in this case
  mutate_p    = data %>% mutate(logOR = log(OR)) %>% select(SNP, A1, logOR),     # same function but with the pipe syntax as formulated by Craig did in the comments
  data.table  = as.data.table(data)[,logOR :=  log(OR)][,.(SNP,A1,logOR)],       # data.table with conversion
  data.table2 = data2[,logOR :=  log(OR)][,.(SNP,A1,logOR)],                     # data.table without conversion, this adds logOR to data2 however
  times = 1000)

# Unit: microseconds
#       expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   transform  202.086  243.4945  281.1694  263.3140  286.6725  6781.367  1000
#      within  290.919  353.2080  395.3183  373.5580  397.4480  7039.017  1000
#        with  279.948  337.8130  406.2508  361.8790  392.1390  7601.388  1000
#      mutate  912.040 1056.2610 1215.2035 1107.4010 1185.4395  8148.541  1000
#    mutate_p 1283.297 1516.7040 1741.8224 1584.3020 1710.2950 33254.564  1000
#  data.table  938.584 1058.5610 1175.6758 1116.7795 1214.4605  5079.035  1000
# data.table2  819.314  935.5755 1086.9992  993.6175 1084.0425 27160.856  1000
```

**bigger data.frames**

```
n <- 100000
...
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
#   transform 3.005094 3.320254 3.978661 3.548707  3.815381  14.87116  1000
#      within 3.252126 3.618074 4.542457 3.929165  4.275118  99.77254  1000
#        with 3.102066 3.413511 4.229389 3.653466  3.937482  89.80346  1000
#      mutate 3.803171 4.221853 4.931597 4.474195  4.815546  26.43214  1000
#    mutate_p 4.283788 4.754672 5.622917 4.996396  5.366238  92.74237  1000
#  data.table 4.831649 6.336141 9.911754 8.212245 12.283330 102.13386  1000
# data.table2 3.997825 4.749894 6.677897 5.456840  6.125562 116.99369  1000
```

*EDIT: Added data.table solutions*

Comment: Thanks for the interesting post. I have never seen transform 'in action' before.